Tefillin removal on chol hamoed - first day vs the other days
For those that wear tefillin on chol hamoed, there seems to be a widespread minhag to remove tefillin on the first day of chol hamoed before mussaf, yet on the other days, one does so earlier - before hallel.
What is the reason for this?

Because that day's laining is about tefillin (according to the Ezra Torah luach p 129)

Interesting thank you!

Is this question about pesach specifically? Because that word doesn’t appear anywhere in it

Not necessarily @JoelK - I can't remember off hand what the practise is on Chol Hamoed Sukkos?

@rosends only pretty recent editions of that luach. Until about 1990 they didn't mention that. One has to wonder if the practice was so widespread before.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70731 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47273

For those who wear tefillin on Chol Hamo'ed Sukkot, the general practice is to remove tefillin before Hallel. On Chol Hamo'ed Pesach the practice is also to remove tefillin before Hallel. (see Mishnah Berurah 25:60 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.25.60?lang=bi) However on first day Chol Hamo'ed Pesach because the kriat hatorah mentions tefillin there is a widespread minhag to remove tefillin only after the conclusion of kriat hatorah.

The Minhag to wear the Tfillin on first day חול המועד פסח is brought, as a by the way, in the ספר לקט הקמח החדש סימן כה אות קח (see image) where he mentions that one should remove the tfillin between shlishi, where the tfillin are mentioned, and revi'i 1. This does not seem to be the common practice (which might be because it is difficult to remove one's tfillin in the short time that the sefer Torah is closed, as it is forbidden to remove tfillin in front of an open Sefer Torah). Rather they are commonly removed after revi'i.
